# Single and double quotes escape sequence in xpth

Tags: python, xml, xpath, elementtree, quotes

I am getting following error while reading the below element from xml file using XPATH.

**XML Element.**

```
<test id="1234" name="PPP_TEST-"WWS"_API's">
```

**Xpath.**

```
value="PPP_TEST-"WWS"_API's"

Xpath=".//test[@name=\"" + value + "\"]/status"
```

**TracePath:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LocalpathPython38-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementPath.py", line 354, in iterfind
    selector = _cache[cache_key]
KeyError: ('.//test[@name="PPP_TEST-"WWS"_API\'s"]/status',)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Localpath\LParser.py", line 58, in <module>
    print(run.get_testcase_execution_status("test", 'name'))
  File "Localpath\Parser.py", line 21, in get_testcase_execution_status
    for status in LogParser.root.findall(".//test[@name=\"" + testcaseNames[i] + "\"]/status"):
  File "Localpath\Python38-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementPath.py", line 395, in findall
    return list(iterfind(elem, path, namespaces))
  File "Localpath\Python38-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementPath.py", line 368, in iterfind
    selector.append(ops[token[0]](next, token))
  File "Localpath\Python38-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementPath.py", line 321, in prepare_predicate
    raise SyntaxError("invalid predicate")
SyntaxError: invalid predicate
```

Could you please help me as to how to apply escaping sequence for both single and double quotes.

Comment: did you able to parse the xml it throwing an error for this `<test id="1234" name="PPP_TEST-"WWS"_API's">`

Comment: The XML is ill-formed. If the attribute value delimiter is the double quote, there cannot be any double quotes in the attribute value.

Comment: Yes. I could parse the name.

Comment: The value of the name is not in my control. So, is there a way to handle these sort of string in xpath???

Comment: how are you able to parse this xml? can you explain?

Comment: Please share the xml and the code that is able to parse it.